# Replace the Nan values with 0 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, nan

Hello i need to replace the Nan values with 0 in my array in java, any help thanks. you can find the example of my array.

The array type is `double` and the contents of array are as follows.

```
x = [ 1 , 2, Nan , 4, Nan ]
```

Comment: what's type of your array?

Comment: it is a double []

Comment: cannot imagine how Nan exist as double in java....

Comment: @forrestg There is a static variable [Double.NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN)

Comment: ok nice to know that, ~~

Comment: DoubleStream.of(values).map(operand -> Double.isNaN(operand) ? 0d : operand).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        double[] doubles = DoubleStream.of(values).map(operand -> Double.isNaN(operand) ? 0d : operand).toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubles));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop the array and use `isNaN` method from `Double` to check if the number is `NaN`.

```java
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(Double.isNaN(array[i])) {
        array[i] = 0d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java Nan != Nan evaluates to true.

```
double[] x = { 1 , 2, Double.NaN , 4, Double.NaN};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i]!=x[i]) {
        x[i] = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, NaN, 4.0, NaN]
[1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Nice trick, but I'll stick with `Double.isNaN` since the equality may change in future version of java.

Comment: This is literally how `isNaN` is implemented in my jdk: `return (v != v)`